# Colors are not printing accurately

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have a brochure which I'm trying to print it has a few shades of purple and grey.

At one printing center, Digital Printing, the colors came out completely wrong as blues instead of purples and very dark gray. I tried a different center and the purple came out kinda pinkish but the gray comes out as yellow.

Originally the file was CMYK but I changed it to RGB later and saved it as PDF which was later used for printing.

Edit: I don't really know the type of the printer but maybe I'll try saving it as CMYK and print it again and see how it turns out

Comment: Are the printers RGB or CMYK??? Sending RGB data to a CMYk printer may be an issue. And color calibration at the "print center" (which you can't control)  is also an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Call the printer company and ask what **Color Profile** (**ICC** colour profile) they use in their printers. If they answer "we don't use any color profile", change to another printing center because this is a copy store, not a printing company.

If they are really professionals, you can get two answers:

- A **Standard color profile**: in this case go to **Menu Edit** > **Assign
  Profile** and choose the standard profile used in your country.
- A **Custom color profile**: ask your printer to send you this profile and
  save it into your OS's Profiles Folder. For Mac users:

  HD > Users > Your User > Library > ColorSync > Profiles

  Maybe be you should restart
  Illustrator to see it in the list and then assign this profile to your document.

[image]

Readjust the colors of your document according to the new profile if necessary.
Save it and send it to print.

---

Remember if your monitor is not properly calibrated, the colors that you see on your screen may differ and quite a lot of those that will appear in printing. The first step before everything is to well calibrate your monitor according to the type of work you usually do.

Comment: This last paragraph about calibration is very important. But the screen is less important than the printed final. If the OP is really having trouble matching colors between systems, then a good last-ditch effort is to make a document of only color swatches, have a proof made by the print-provider, pick the color swatches that match closest to the ideal, and then set those colors in a document used specifically for the printing. Basically a homebrew swatchbook