# Photoshop Color Management: Proof with Xerox Versalink C500 different from CMYK production printer?

Tags: print-production, color-profile, color-spaces

I'm having a hard time getting accurate colors between calibration on my monitor; a Xerox C500 i'm using to proof, and the end result when sent to our production printer. I'm not sure exactly where my issue is:

**Photoshop:**

1. Color Settings: North America Prepress 2
2. RGB: Adobe RGB 1998
3. CMYK: US Web Coated SWPO v2
4. Gray: Dot Gain 20%
5. Spot: Dot Gain 20%
6. Color Management: Preserve Embedded Profiles, Ask on mismatches
7. Advanced: Blend text colors using gamma: 1.45
8. Monitor is calibrated (X-Rite)

**Proofing Printer (Xerox C500):**

1. Using latest Xerox postscript driver
2. Have the printer ICC profile installed (Should i use printer profile or monitor profile?)
3. When printing: "Allow printer to manage colors"

**Problems:**

- The screen differs quite a bit from my proof on the C500, especially when dealing with blues that come up much more purple.
- If i send the same proof to our print shop, i get even more magenta and more purple when intended to have blue.
- Its also an issue printing people, as they appear more red then skin toned.

I understand there will be slight variation between my monitor, the printer, and our print shop, but these are way off to the point where i just have to manually back out magenta to get it look acceptable. I'm confused to where my problem actually lies?

**Additional Information**

- If i increase brightness +40 and back off the M channel i get skin tones that look somewhat natural when printed, but they look yellow/green on screen, and much brighter on screen versus printed.
- As a test, I created a new document used my Pantone color bridge to set some swatches to known CMYK values and printed. The printed colors come out accurate, leading me to believe it may be a problem with the entire set of images i'm working with?
- Assigning the ICC profile to the document does little to get it to render accurately

Comment: Hi DDulla, welcome to GD.SE. You should ask the printer for the color profile they use in their machines, read [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/115061/120647)

Comment: Probably you want to take a look at some calibration hardware https://www.xrite.com/categories/calibration-profiling/i1studio

Answer (score 0):

You should use same CMYK profile for printer and for Adobe products. If printer have native ICC profile, then use this profile also in InDesign/Photoshop/Etc.

Comment: I have an ICC profile. In Photoshop Edit > Assign Profile > Select the ICC profile from the list. I still have darkness / magenta problem. If i adjust the image brightness around +40, and lower the entire M channel around 20-30%, it looks washed out on monitors and skin tones look yellow/green-ish; but i get fairly close to printing the colors correctly. Still stumped.

Comment: What ICC profile are you talking about?