# When converting RGB to CMYK colour changes in print output

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, print-production, rgb

I am designing a poster in pink colour in RGB mode. The printing person ask me a CMYK file. I changed the mode to CMYK and send it to them, but when output comes the colour totally changes, it turns into purple from pink. What can I do?

Comment: See this Graphic Design [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/how-does-a-monitor-display-the-cmyk-color-is-it-actually-showing-the-true-cmyk)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is the actual hex code of the RGB colour you are having trouble with?  Some RGB colours are out of gamut for CMYK printing. That means they can't be printed in CMYK. Also what profile are you using to convert to CMYK? Have you asked your printer which colour profile they'd like you to use?  Also is your monitor calibrated?  All these things could potentially contribute to the problem.

Comment: [Related answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/115061/120647)